# FCM takes time to start working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM takes time to start working when I launch it for the first time after installing my app.I am asking for time taken after exchanging FCM token.
Any idea what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On first run of your app, FCM has to connect to Google servers to authenticate your app instance for FCM. It receives a security token in return for authentication when sending messages. The token is cached to make future runs faster.

Comment: In addition to this answer, you should also consider the device load and network connection, since the app needs to connect to FCM servers on initial start up and will generate a device registration token which usually takes less than 10 seconds.